Why documents with different mimetypes are output normally
I have two printers.
1. Eson L6290
- "application/octet-stream"
- "image/pwg-raster"
- "image/urf"
- "image/jpeg"
- "application/vnd.epson.escpr"

 3.SAMSUN SL-M2830DW
- "application/octet-stream"
- "application/PCL"
- "application/vnd.hp-PCL"
- "application/vnd.hp-PCLXL"
- "application/x-QPDL"
- "text/plain"
- "image/urf"

I have a document in pwg-raster format. Let's say this is test.pwg.
Now print the document using cups.
if (cupsStartDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo, nJobId, "test.pwg", mimeType, 0, NULL, lastPage) == HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE){
            while ((bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), pOut)) > 0)
            {
                if (cupsWriteRequestData(pHttp, buffer, bytes) != HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)
                    break;
            }

            if (cupsFinishDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo) != IPP_STATUS_OK)
            {
                LOG("Document send failed: %s", cupsLastErrorString());
                szResult = cupsLastErrorString();
            }else{
                LOG("Document send success: %s", cupsLastErrorString());
                szResult = cupsLastErrorString();
            }
        }else{
            LOG("cupsStartDestDocument != HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE");
        }

To improve readability, I've attached only the code that requests printing to the actual printer.
The curious thing here is that printer number 2 does not support the "image/pwg-raster" format, but if you set the mimeType variable to "application/PCL" and "image/urf", it will be printed normally. Below is an example.
if (cupsStartDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo, nJobId, "test.pwg", "application/PCL", 0, NULL, lastPage) == HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE) ...

if (cupsStartDestDocument(pHttp, pDest, pInfo, nJobId, "test.pwg", "image/urf", 0, NULL, lastPage) == HTTP_STATUS_CONTINUE)...

